# Dates on x-axis; big dataset

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot a time series. I created an example to show how the graph should look like:

```
 set.seed(1)
    r <- rnorm(20,0,1)
    z <- c(1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1)
    data <- as.data.frame(na.omit(cbind(z, r)))
    series1 <- ts(cumsum(c(1,data[,2]*data[,1])))
    series2 <- ts(cumsum(c(1,data[,2])))
    d1y <- seq(as.Date("1991-01-01"),as.Date("2015-01-01"),length.out=21)
    plot_strategy <- function(series1, series2, currency)

{x11()
 matplot(cbind(series1, series2), xaxt = "n", xlab = "Time", 
         ylab = "Value", col = 1:3, ann = TRUE, type = 'l',  
         lty = 1)
 axis(1, at=seq(2,20,2), labels=format(d1y[seq(2,20,2)],"%Y"))

 legend(x = "topleft", legend = c("TR", "BA"),
        lty = 1,col = 1:3)
 dev.copy2pdf(file= currency, width = 11.69, height = 8.27)}

plot_strategy(series1, series2,
              currency= "all.pdf")
```

The actual dataset contains 6334 values. I therefore change the code to this:

```
axis(1, at=seq(2,6334,365), labels=format(d1y[seq(2,6334,365)],"%Y"))
```

But now, there are no values on the x-axis. Any suggstions?

Comment: An example that does not reproduce your problem is quite useless. Try to find a better reproducible example.